# AngularJS $broadcast name gets reset to an empty string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to implement the Angular Dashboard Framework found here

https://github.com/angular-dashboard-framework/angular-dashboard-framework

Within the main dashboard.js code (https://github.com/angular-dashboard-framework/angular-dashboard-framework/blob/master/src/scripts/dashboard.js) there is this line:

```
if (!$scope.editMode){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('adfDashboardChanged', name, model);
   }
```

I set a breakpoint in the angular.js code where the $broadcast function is defined:

```
$broadcast: function(name, args) {
    var target = this,
        current = target,
        next = target,
        etc...
```

The "name" parameter is an empty string, even though I'm definitely passing it the event name 'adfDashboardChanged.' Because this value is somehow, somewhere getting re-set to an empty string, my $on listener never picks it up.

Why would this value be getting re-set?

Comment: don't pass `name` as an arg to `$broadcast`;  if you must pass an arg with the name `name`, wrap it in an object.

Comment: Good thought, but I already tried changing that by renaming that variable, and it still doesn't broadcast the event. Also, the demo code at the link listed above works using this same code, so I'm thinking it's something else.